# Customize Taskbar Icon based on light vs dark theme

Tags: windows-11, taskbar, themes

I manage a fleet of around 250 workstations. We have a custom app for many of our users that we pin to the taskbar by default. The icon is designed to mimic the style of some of the built-in Windows icons like search, task view, sound, network status, etc, via the Segoe Icon font, so the icon is simple white lines over a transparent background. This worked great for Windows 10, which is dark by default, and even the light view still had enough contrast.

Unfortunately, the icon lacks contrast in the default Windows 11 theme, and if I make it dark enough to show well there you lose contrast again if the user switches to dark. The built-in Windows icons somehow know how to render using white lines or black lines depending on context. Can I make my own icon do the same? Otherwise, is there a way to detect this and adjust the icon when the theme changes?

Comment: Windows Dark / Light require Custom Settings to get the Task Bar to show up properly. I don't see how you will set task bar custom settings for 250 computers.

Comment: @John There are a number of ways to do this, including Group Policy and MDM, but in this case I'm working on the initial Windows 11 image template, so as we get new machines through our normal refresh process these settings will be part of the initial image/configuration for the PCs. In short, if I can get an icon that works in both scenarios, I can get the Windows to use it when I want. I just need to know how to build the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has the ability to create icons with inverted colors.
For example, I'm using mouse cursors that use the inverse of their
background, so are visible everywhere.

The question is how to create such icons.

I have found in a Microsoft article, pertaining apparently to
Visual Studio, the following
[reference to inverse regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/creating-an-icon-or-other-image-image-editor-for-icons?view=msvc-170#to-create-transparent-or-inverse-regions-in-device-images):

> In the Image Editor, the initial icon or cursor image has a transparent attribute. Although icon and cursor images are rectangular, many don't appear so because parts of the image are transparent and the underlying image on the screen shows through the icon or cursor. When you drag an icon, parts of the image may appear in an inverted color. You create this effect by setting the screen color and inverse color in the Colors window.

There may exist other icon editors that can create inversed icons,
but I can't recommend any,